# How can I send a notification based on the users location, regardless if the app is running? [Swift 2.0]

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to send a notification to the user if they are at a certain location. Even if the app is terminated, they should retrieve a notification saying they are at x location. I have set up all the stuff for push notification and parse, but I am not sure where to implement the code because I don't think I can post the code inside a random view controller because it won't be called if it is in the background or terminated, so I am assuming I have to put it somewhere in the app delegate. I also need the coordinates for the location imported from parse, but how would I do this if the app is not running, I don't think it is possible. Essentially what I want is the have 4 locations stored in parse, and if a user is near any of those locations they would get a notification.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. It goes in AppDelegate. `func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])`

Comment: Are you doing geo fencing? Are you looking where to put the location services code?

Comment: I am not familiar with geo fencing.

Comment: Check this out [Core Location Tutorial: Geofencing](https://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift)

Comment: I updated my question